# Alternatives for '¡dame un respiro!'

Tags: traducción

Are there other alternatives for 'dame un respiro'?

> ¡Dame un respiro, acabo de llegar del trabajo! ¡Dame tres horas para
>   descansar!

Comment: "Dejame vivir" It could be funny, or rude, depending on context and tone. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VENkNeay3jE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Calma, dame un momento, acabo de llegar del trabajo!

Answer (score 6):

Podría decir:

¡Déjame en paz!

¡Déjame ya!

¡Déjame tranquilo!

Answer (score 2):

¡No me agobies!

This phrase is very common in Spain, especially in informal speech, among younger people, between friends and in the family. It sounds more aggressive than merely "dame un respiro". It might be frequent in other countries/regions, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

¡Calmame un rato!

¡Calmala, calmala!

¡Dame chance un rato!

¡Deja descanso un rato!

All of them are from northern México.

Answer (score 1):

También podríamos usar las expresiones: "Espérate un momento, por favor, acabo de llegar", o "Enseguida voy, acabo de llegar".

En la primera pides un momento antes de empezar con la siguiente tarea, en la segunda das a entender que tu pausa será muy breve, y que empezarás en un instante.